# Generic restriction on constructor

Tags: java, generics

Any ideas why the code below doesn't compile?

```
public class A<TT extends B<?>> extends C<TT> implements D<TT> {

    protected A(Class<TT> c) {
        super(c);
    }

}

interface B<MM> {

}

interface D<MM extends B<?>> {

}

abstract class C<TT> {
    protected C(Class<TT> c) {

    }
}

class F implements B<String> {

}

class G extends F {

}

class E<TT extends B<String>> {
    public E() {
        // why does this not work?
        // Error: The constructor A<TT>(Class<G>) is undefined
        D<TT> d = new A<TT>(G.class);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: `G.class` is a `Class<G>` - not a `Class<TT>`.

This works:

```
D<G> d = new A<G>(G.class);
```

... but you don't know the type of `TT` (in E) so you can't provide the relevant `Class<TT>` instance to the `A<TT>` constructor. This would compile too, but probably isn't what you want:

```
// Oops - we don't really have TT.class, and can't refer to it...
D<TT> d = new A<TT>(null);
```

Imagine we tried to use your current code, and had:

```
class H extends B<String> {}
```

Then it would be entirely reasonable to construct an `E<H>`, but you'd be trying to pass `G.class` to the constructor of `A<H>` - it's clearly not the same type.

(As a side-note, it's really helpful to make these examples as simple as possible. That means getting rid of all the classes which aren't relevant, and avoiding reusing type parameter names for the sake of clarity.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it works. The implication is  that I have to instantiate a "new A<SpecificClass>" for every single SpecificClass that extends B<?>. I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: Actually, your answer helped me realise that the solution is to add a Class<TT> c parameter to the methods of class A and remove the parameter Class<TT> c from the constructor - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an actual class to replace TT:

```
new A<G>(G.class);
```

The compiler should be able to infer the type without even stating it explicitly:

```
new A(G.class);
```

Comment: It's reasonable to use `new A<TT>` - for example, you could create an `ArrayList<TT>` - the only problem is that we don't have a `Class<TT>` to pass into the constructor.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: but TT is a template variable, what sense would it make to initiate a templated instance of a variable without an actual type ?

Comment: Potentially it makes perfect sense. It's hard to tell from the situation, but it can definitely make sense to create (say) an `ArrayList<T>` within a generic class using type parameter `T`. The problem here is that we need to provide the concrete class too.

Comment: @Yochai Timmer: Thanks for your answer - it works but gives the following warning - Type safety: The expression of type A needs unchecked conversion to conform to D<TT>

Comment: @loudsight : You could specify explicitly that D is of type G: D<G> d = new A<G>(G.class);

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Interesting, never seen that done, do you have an example somewhere ? (would like to see how it's used)

Comment: @Yochai: Not offhand, but imagine one possible implementation of `HashSet<E>` which used a `HashMap<K, V>` internally...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the constructor argument doesn't match: G.class isn't String.class (TT).